# Generating emirps stop when a user enters a zero or negative integer.

Tags: java, primes

I have created a program using Java that generates emirps by user input, but I need help on stopping the user when entering zero or a negative integer. I have tried many things but when I run the program with zero or a negative number it will go crazy and give me infinite amount of numbers. I would appreciate it if someone could help me on this.

Here is what I got so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GenerateEmirps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of desired emirps: ");

        int emrips = scanner.nextInt();
        int count = 1;

        for( int i = 2; ; i++){
            if ((isPrime(i)) && (isPrime(reverseIt(i))) && (!isPalindrome(i))) {
                System.out.print(i + "       ");

                if (count % 10 == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                }

                if (count == emrips){
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int num){
        for (int i = 2; i <=num / 2; i++){
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int reverseIt(int num){
        int result = 0;

        while (num != 0) {
            int lastDigit = num % 10;
            result = result * 10 + lastDigit;
            num /= 10;
    }
        return result;
        }
        public static boolean isPalindrome(int num){
        return num == reverseIt(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You just need to test the input before you process it.

```
int emrips = scanner.nextInt();

if (emrips <= 0) { System.exit(0); }
```